# Can I access MS Access file as Database for ASP.NET site without SQL hosting plan?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2007

I am creating a site with ASP.NET C#. Now my problem is I purchased one hosting plan without SQL database hosting, so can I use MS Access as my database for my site? I have taken hosting plan from [net4.in](http://www.net4.in/).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it's possible or not, but I wouldn't recommend it. Access is meant to be a single user database, not to back a web front-end.

Comment: Possible if they have Microsoft Office license on their hosting environment.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar i think you are right but i want to know that does net4.in has Microsoft office installed or not ? Or is there any way that i can check whether the server has Microsoft Office installed or not

Comment: why not try one of the sql server compact / express

Comment: You do not need Office installed to use Access as a web database. You need the Jet OleDb driver installed. You can test that by uploading an mdb file and a test page that connects to it.

Comment: @MikeBrind or the more recent ACE.

Comment: @Remou You are unlikely to find many hosting companies that support the ACE provider. If you must use Access, I recommend saving as a 2003 mdb file. You will find Jet much more widely available, but test first. In any event, if you want a file based system, you should use SQL Compact 4.0. That's the MS recommended solution.

Comment: The ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver is also used with text and Excel (xlsx) so it is becoming more common. Access is certainly not a good choice for a proper web site, but is a great way to pass around smallish amounts of organized data, for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Make sure you have the appropriate security access to the file - this can typically be done by putting the Access .mdb file in the App_Data 'magic' folder in ASP.NET. Update the connection string in your application configuration / web.config with the appropriate values.

Refer to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007) for building / configuring the connection string.

Not all features available in SQL Server are available in Access and there might be slight changes to your queries / SQL syntax so make sure Access has everything you want before you go down this route - the extra cost of switching / upgrading your host will probably be less than modifying and retesting your code.

EDIT: ASP.NET also supports disconnected database MDF files in the App_Data - it might be worth checking with your host if they support this as you would not need to alter your code at all.

Comment: ok but the problem is i don't know whether my hosting plan will support Microsoft file or not.

Comment: You hosting plan does not need to support Microsoft Access > they just need to have Jet / ACE drivers installed (most will have one or the other installed).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, however I'd strongly recommend against it. The reasons for using Sql Server are limitless. Sql Server is much more secure and it performs better than Access when it comes to optimizing queries. The Sql Server Query Optimizer is remarkable in its ability to analyze the optimum route for pulling back data and is very efficient in preserving  server resources.
  However, if you are unable to pay the price for Sql hosting then you can certainly use Access. This article: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Connecting-to-a-Microsoft-Access-database-with-ASPNET/ can help you get started... it is outdated, but it should get you on the right path for setting up the connection string to grant your application access to your MS Access data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer but i tried by myself [downloaded](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3517/ASP-NET-Guestbook-using-MS-Access) one sample application and uploaded on my server, and its working. So now i can use MS Access database on my server which   is without SQL server hosting. As there was very small need for using database so i used MS Access here.